# Moving sqlite output into bash array

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am trying to load some sqlite3 output into an /n-delimited bash array.
Seems like it should be a simple thing, but the read statement doesn't seem to produce any output. Echoing fqry just prior to the IFS statement confirms that the sqlite query is loading its output into a string correctly. But nothing appears to be getting into farray at all.

```
cmd="SELECT * FROM format"
fqry=`sqlite3 data.db "$cmd"`
IFS=$'\n' 
read -ra farray <<< "$fqry"
for f in "${farray[@]}"
do
echo "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Use compound array assignment to create an indexed array instead of `read`:

```
cmd="SELECT * FROM format"
IFS=$'\n'
fqry=(`sqlite3 data.db "$cmd"`)

for f in "${fqry[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: what if the entries contain newlines?

Comment: @Blauhirn then it gets complicated using bash. No matter what output line separator or IFS you use, you won't have any guarantee that it won't also appear in the db. Safest way would be to count the number of lines and then execute a query for each line (using LIMIT ...), but that has obvious drawbacks and is not atomic... I'd probably just use python instead.

Comment: @mata ok thanks. I solved it using `select replace(the_column, char(10), 'my_linebreak_replacement12321') from ...` and handle it accordingly. not optimal, but enough for my case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `read -d` option to define another delim, rather than the default newline character `\n`, to indicate the termination of the input line,

```
read -d '' -ra farray <<< "$fqry"
```